# Two phase commit in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, transactions

Having carefully reading [the online documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/), I still have a lot of questions about two phase commit in MongoDB.

In the section **Recovering from Failure Scenarios**, why are there only two classes of failures? In my thinking failure can happen in any of these step so there should be a lot more than two classes here. For example what if, (in **Apply Transaction to Both Accounts** section), after updating account A the database server failed. That means account A lost some money without anything happen on account B. And we would have inconsistent transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my thinking failure can happen in any of these step so there should be a lot more than two classes here.

The key thing to remember here is that the documentation is NOT a definitive guide on two phase commits, in reality two phase commits are technically impossible in MongoDB and I would strongly recommend you get an ACID tech if you want to perform them.

You must remember that there are certain fail scenarios that you cannot counter due to this not being within the server itself. Instead the whole existance of two phase commits is only client side as such it is quite flimsy compared to say TTL monitoring.

> after updating account A the database server failed. That means account A lost some money without anything happen on account B. And we would have inconsistent transaction?

In support of Philipps answer the original transaction between account A and B would still be pending in this case, it will only be moved to finished/completed once account B has been updated.

This means the transaction cannot be marked as completed until it is.

Instead of using MongoDB for a scenario that it isn't really designed for I would recommend using something that is designed for your scenario.

Comment: Why saying multiple times MongoDB cannot truly implement two phase commit and talking about ACID ? You should have satisfied yourself with the right answer which is part of your answer. MongoDB can support real 2 phase commit indeed, and this is possible thanks to the ability you have of marking a modified document (here an account) with the transaction. All recovery scenario are possible here.

Comment: @rpechayr MongoDB does not hold transactional locks for one, the very fundamentals of MongoDBs concurrency breaks the ACID paradigm. It can support operations which allow rollback but without global lock across all shards you will find those operations are still prone to many problems, TokuMX uses a global lock to implement its transactions

Comment: @rpechayr where do I say that 2 phase commits are supported? It is good to know that the 2 phase commit the Docs mention is not really what goes on in ACID databases

Comment: I would be interested in knowing about these many problems that can happen. What is interesting about two phase commit in MongoDB is that it enables people to implement eventually consistent transactions *without* requiring a global lock, which does not scale.

Comment: @rpechayr I think the biggest problem is that this consistentcy is provided client side, it is not in any way, shape or form, provided within mongodb itself. That provides enough problems. Also documents can be modified and go out of date during a MongoDB "transaction" over multiple documents. As such in a two phase commit you cannot always say you are updating the right document.

Comment: @rpechayr In an ACID database you can rely on the documents being the same state throughout the duration of the transaction. I am sure there are also edge cases within recovery, I have never implemented ACID paradigms into a non-ACID database...for obvious reasons

Comment: The original question was about how to rescue failure between account A and B in MongoDB 2-phase commit process. It was not about "should I use MongoDb" or not, nor was it about is "MongoDB ACID" or not. What is interesting about two-phase commit in MongoDB is that it actually allows people to have real life transactions in scalable systems. Even bank account balances are not always handled by ACID transactions: http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/93523827905/how-to-implement-robust-and-scalable-transactions.

Comment: @rpechayr may I ask if you know of a bank that does not? I would like to make sure my account is not with them. 10gen employees say many things, sometimes you wouldn't use stuff they say in such an environment. The part of my question you are contesting was added for clarity, I answered the question in the second half of my answer. I also stand by what I said in the first half, there will always be certain fail scenarios that might cause breakage (I mean think about rollbacks in replica sets, technically should not exist on majority, but can)

Comment: @rpechayr I also stand by saying that the docs are not a definitive guide. Seems to relate to the question since the OP wishes to implement 2PC that way. The only part which is not strictly to the question is a single line. Essentially my entire answer says, "this should happen, but I cannot say it will always be that way". Apart form my own personal recommendation of using an ACID database everything else is centered around answering. In this case, using ACID paradigms with no-ACID databases I believe I can add such a line since it is on-topic.

Comment: you recommendation is more than clear, and this is what puzzles me about your answer, it is advertising too much against non ACID dbs. Two-phase commit has nothing to do with replica sets, since you update documents by making sure they have the right field values and you update them in one query which happens on the primary, since this is were the writes happen.

Comment: I don't know about a bank not using ACID transactions (nor do I know for a fact anyone using ACID transactions), but using log reconciliation makes a lot of sense and allows a maximum performance. Transaction validations can be done using mongoish two-phase commit without any problems (apart from the *things* that can go wrong like many people cannot tell anything about). FYI, I'll let you have the final say if you'd like. I think we've both said what we had to at least twice :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65549/discussion-between-rpechayr-and-sammaye).

Comment: @rpechayr indeed however, I believe you may have mis-understood what I said about replica sets, it was used as an example. Anyway as you have just said we have both explained ourselves. However, I do know that Natwest uses ACID technologies.

Answer (score 8):

When the application or database suddenly crashes between applying the transaction to A and applying the transaction to B, there will still be a transaction with `state:"pending"` in the global transaction collection. Your recovery script which you run after a crash should notice this, check the two accounts, and see that there is a pending transaction in one, but not the other account. It now knows everything it needs to know to either rollback the transaction or try to complete it.

Yes, writing a recovery script which is that smart isn't easy. But transactions in a database system not designed for them is always hard. Sometimes you can work around requiring transactions in MongoDB by designing your documents in a way that fields which need to be updated together are always in the same document, but there isn't always a sane way to do this. When your use-case absolutely needs transactions, protect your sanity and use a relational database.

Comment: Just a note to the last point. There are non-relational databases with transaction support, so you don't have to use a relational db to keep sanity :)

Answer (score 0):

the online document may not be perfect.
in fact you do need to rollback operations on A and B